# Derivative notation - quick overview

Tags: derivatives, notation

Just a quick question, hopefully someone can give me a general overview of the rules of derivative notation. (I'm in my first year of a Physics degree and would just like some clarification).

What would the derivatives of:

$$
\dot{a}
$$

and

$$
\frac{1}{2}\dot{a}^{2} 
$$

be? I'm thinking it is:

$$
\ddot{a}\dot{a}
$$

$$
\dot{a}+\frac{1}{2}\ddot{a}\dot{a}^{2}
$$

? If this is wrong, then that is fair. However, what are the general rules for such a notation?

Comment: How do you get such unexpected results ??

Comment: I think I'm applying the chain rule.

Comment: You can apply the chain rule when there is a composition of functions. But here ??

Comment: Yes. I thought that as we had the derivative and the squared factor it warranted it.

Comment: Indeed, it works with $f(x)=\frac12x^2$, $\dot{ f(\dot a)}=f'(\dot a)\ddot a=\dot a\ddot a$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The derivative of $\dot{a}$ is, by definition, $\ddot{a}$.

The derivative of ${1\over 2}\dot{a}^2$ is: ${1 \over 2} \cdot 2 \cdot (\dot{a}) \cdot (\dot{a})' = \dot{a}\cdot\ddot{a}$, because, for any $f$, $(f^2)' = 2 \cdot f \cdot f'$ (apply for $f = \dot{a}$).

Just remember that $\dot{f} = f'$, $\ddot{f} = f''$ and use general rules for derivatives.

Answer (score 2):

They are
$$
\ddot{a} 
$$

$$
\ddot{a}\dot{a}
$$

You should not retain the original in first case as if it is a chain rule. In the second you should be  differentiating w.r.t. $\dot {a}$ and then multiply with its derivative.

Answer (score 1):

Yes they are wrong.

The notation follows this rule:

> If $a=a(t)$ where $t$ is an arbitrary parameter i.e. $a$ is a function
>   of some parameter $t$, then the notations $\large\frac{da}{dt}$ and $a'$ and 
>   $\dot{a}$ mean the same.

The correct answers hence in order are : $\ddot{a}$ and $\dot{a}\ddot{a}$

Comment: @Narasimham Yes, typo corrected.

Answer (score 1):

If $\dot{a}$ denotes the first derivative (this notation is usually used if the variable in question is a single variable named $t$ - the time), then the derivative of the derivative is the second derivative:

$\dot{(\dot{a})}=\ddot{a}$, or $(a')'=a''$.

For the derivative of $\frac{1}{2}\dot{a}^2$, there are multiple ways to get an anwswer, for instance you can write this as $\frac{1}{2}\dot{a}^2$ = $\frac{1}{2}(\dot{a} \cdot \dot{a}),$ or $\frac{1}{2}a' \cdot a'$.

We have: $\frac{1}{2}(a' \cdot a')' = \frac{1}{2}(a''a' \cdot a'a'') = a'a'',$ thus the second derivative is equal to $\dot{a}\ddot{a}$.